# Why most people create mutator method with parameter name similar to class attribute?

Tags: java

I know this would sound like a dumb question, but I just want to know the relevance  of why most people create a mutator method like:

```
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
```

instead of:

```
public void setName(String input) {name = input;}
```

Is there any reason to it or is it just me that have a thought like that? Sorry if my English was bad.

Comment: Personal preference a lot of the time, especially if you have multiple parameters

Comment: `input` is a very broad term, in general you prefer to give specific name to parameters.

Comment: Convention, mostly. The [JavaBeans spec](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javabeans-spec.html) doesn't dictate it (and actually has examples resembling your second example). Another reason is that often developers use their IDE to generate getters and/or setters. The IDE doesn't get creative and just uses the property name.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah I see, so rather than we take a time to think new words for variable name, we just use the same name directly right?

Comment: you will be confused if the attributes of a class becomes too large, and it will help you to make faster and better decision to pick the right elements for input parameter when you use the method outside of the class.

Comment: See you choose class field name to be most intuitive and easy to understand it's use. Naturally it's good to choose the same name for your method parameter. This way when people see your API documentation looking at method parameter they immediately get what it is used for. If you are not using the parameter as it is then you can have other name for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that is more readable. If you want identified fields in your class **clearly** you shouldn't use two different names for them.

For example, if you have class `Invoice` with field `tax` is there a better name that does not change meaning? If yes - change field name if no, you should use that name **everywhere** in your code instead of other substitutes.

It is less readable and confusing. If you use an accessor elsewhere in your code, you'd better be sure of the meaning of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier for someone using method to understand what does parameter stands for if name of parameter is specific. Using correct names can save efforts to add comment to explain about parameters.